# Как с помощью C получить все символы от начала файла до пробела

Tags: c, файлы, строки

Нужно из файла `/etc/issue.net` получить название дистрибутива.

Синтаксис файла: "название-дистрибутива прочая информация".

Нужно получить "название-дистрибутива".

Comment: strchr() поможет найти первый пробел в буфере, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, так:

```
# file: firstword.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fp;
  char word[1000];

  fp = fopen ("/etc/issue.net", "r");
  fscanf(fp,"%s%*[^\n]",word);
  printf("%s\n", word);

  fclose(fp);
  return(0);
}
```

проверка:

```
$ make firstword
cc     firstword.c   -o firstword
$ ./firstword 
Debian
```

---

пример взят из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756495/4827341).